# Archive folder to record center based on Modified date

Tags: sharepoint-online, records-center

My scenario: I am using SharePoint Online. I have lot of projects that are represented as a folder in a library. some of those folders are no more in use and need to be archive(send to record center). I am looking for an automatic solution to archive folder based on the Last Modified Date + 3 years.

I have seen retention policy being used on content type but in my case i don't have any.

Answer (score 0):

Retention policy would apply to items in the folder. I would probably try a flow workflow to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Please explain the workflow? If i have Project A(Folder ),how do i ensure that a folder name Project(A) is going to be created automatically in the record center to store the archived items?

Comment: Create Flow, make a query that will only return folders that have items meeting your criteria, then you copy that folder over and delete the source folder.